# Windows Server Network Shares - Non-domain users have access

Tags: active-directory, network-share, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server with Windows Server 2012 R2. I have a drive that I want to share with the "Domain Users" group. I have set that drive to share only with that group.

From a different computer that is on the domain, I have logged in with a *local* account (i.e. this user  is not listed in the "Domain Users" group in Active Directory). For some reason, this local user can access the network share that is only supposed to be for domain users.

Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: Does the local user by chance have the same *username* and *password* as a valid domain user?  Have you ever accessed that server while logged in with this local account, provided valid domain credentials and selected the `Save this password` checkbox?

Comment: Hahaha... actually it does have the same username and password. That's hilarious, I never thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a domain member server while logged in as a local user, Windows *automatically attempts to logon the server with the local user's credentials*. If your local username and password happen to match that of a valid domain account, you'll be granted access to the server, and in your case, be able to browse the share you've created.

Comment: That's the trick, thanks! I didn't realize it would do that for a user on a different domain (i.e. the local machine)